# Date formatting with IYYY in PostgreSQL gives strange result

Tags: postgresql, date, iso

Date formatting with IYYY vs YYYY:

```
SELECT to_char( '2012-12-31'::DATE, 'IYYY-MM-DD' ) AS weird,
       to_char( '2012-12-31'::DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) AS expected;
```

Result:

```
   weird    |  expected  
------------+------------
 2013-12-31 | 2012-12-31
```

It would not be *this* surprised if the "weird" result was "2013-01-01".

What's wrong here ? (PostgreSQL 9.1.7)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IYYY` refers to the year of the week of the specified date.

The first week of 2013 starts on Monday, 31 December 2012, so the weird result in the question is correct.

There's a warning directly related to this in the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html):

> Attempting to construct a date using a mixture of ISO week and
>   Gregorian date fields is nonsensical, and will cause an error. In the
>   context of an ISO year, the concept of a "month" or "day of month" has
>   no meaning. In the context of a Gregorian year, the ISO week has no
>   meaning. Users should avoid mixing Gregorian and ISO date
>   specifications.

See also wikipedia [iso week date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) article for lots of details.